# Why server shows default Apache page instead of my app?

Tags: apache2

I setup Php+Mysql app on my Ec2 instance but when I reach domain,Apache default page is shown.
Bookstack is my app.
tail log

```
172.68.50.230 - - [21/Apr/2022:05:26:52 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 2539 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.75 Safari/537.36"
```

My default.conf output
cat 000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/certs/pizd.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/certs/pizd.key
</VirtualHost>
```

My bookstack.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName bookstack

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/bookstack/public/

    <Directory /var/www/bookstack/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
                Options -MultiViews -Indexes
            </IfModule>

            RewriteEngine On

            # Handle Authorization Header
            RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
            RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

            # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
            RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

            # Handle Front Controller...
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

I checked this

```
sudo ls -l /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 338 Apr 20 14:20 000-default.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  33 Apr 18 09:38 bookstack.conf -> ../sites-available/bookstack.conf
```

What should I try?

Comment: Are you sure your `000-default.conf` is not causing any problems?

Comment: @paladin I do not know,I just added the content.

Comment: I suggest to you to know more about it.

Comment: Please add the content of bookstack.conf as well.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Just added.

Comment: Are you trying to reach your server via HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: https,( Record on my company's Cloudflare)

Comment: Then you need to add a VirtualHost for that Server with Port 443.

Answer (score 0):

First, check if the apache ssl-module is enabled yet with: `sudo a2enmod ssl`.

Then add the following lines into your `000-default.conf` right after the `DocumentRoot` part:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/bookstack/public/>
Options FollowSymlinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted</Directory>
```

Comment: Module ssl already enabled.

Comment: Have your restarted your apache2?
Try `sudo systemctl restart apache2`